# winforms listview not showing items in detailsview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

i'm stuck....

this my code to add items to my listview:

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(ProjectDomainName);
item.Tag = relatedProject.ProjectId;
lvwSelectedProjects.Items.Add(item);
```

when i choose `'View.List'` as viewmode, i see all items.

When i choose `'View.Details'` (which is the setting that i want) i see.... nothing. Well, nothing,  i DO get a vertical scrollbar, but no items. And i can scroll too, but no items....

I also added a column in the listview (didn't change the add items code), but that also didn't work

i must be overlooking something?

Comment: I think you are going to have to provide more details. There is nothing wrong with the code you've provided for adding items to the list view, it's the 'View.Details' that I'm not sure about. What is 'View' and what is 'Details'? Unsure about what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: `View.List` and `view.details` are values for the `View` property of the lisview: `lvwAvailableProjects.View = View.Details;`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class LVTest : Form {
    public LVTest() {
        ListView lv = new ListView();
        lv.Columns.Add("Header", 100);
        lv.Columns.Add("Details", 100);
        lv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        lv.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { "Alpha", "Some details" }));
        lv.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { "Bravo", "More details" }));
        lv.View = View.Details;
        Controls.Add(lv);
    }
}

public static class Program {
    [STAThread] public static void Main() {
        Application.Run(new LVTest());
    }
}
```

Try this code for yourself in an empty project.  Then, focus on adapting it to your application:  compare how your program is different from this code, and work on changing it to more closely match mine.  It's OK if you lose functionality in your program; just try to get a basic version working.  Then, add functionality back bit by bit so you can be sure that the program still works every step of the way.

If you're still stuck, post more code from your project and we might have a better idea of why you're having trouble.

Comment: Thank you, this pointed me in the right direction. What the problem was? I reloaded the listview every time with new data, and i did a lvw.Clear() to clear the list, but that also clears the columns, so no items are shown in details mode. It had to be lvw.Items.Clear()....

Comment: Thanks for the the solution.  Use lv.Items.Clear() and not lv.Clear()

Answer (score 3):

Another possible cause of blank items when listview.View = View.Details, is if you *don't add any columns* to the listview.

For example:

```
ListView lv = new ListView();
lv.View = View.Details;
lv.Items.Add("Test");
```

.. will result in a blank ListView.
Adding a column will correct:

```
...
lv.View = View.Details;
// Add one auto-sized column, to show Text field of each item.
lv.Columns.Add("YourColumnTitle", -2);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Because, you should be using a ListViewDataItem instead of a ListViewItem, observe ...

```
        for (int i = 0; i < AudioCdWriter.FileCount; ++i) {
            var item = new ListViewDataItem(i.ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(AudioCdWriter.TrackLength((short)i).ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(AudioCdWriter.file[(short)i]);
            lvwAudioFiles.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

Comment: **When** "should" you use a `ListViewDataItem` instead of a `ListViewItem`?

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me as well (listview not showing items in details view) I just put the following into the code (previously was only in the design) after adding items to the listview and it started showing the items.

```
lv.View = View.Details;
```

Comment: FWIW: I did not downvote it, but without more information, its not clear *what you did wrong in the first place* such that this "fixed" it. If the listview was already in Details view (as set in Designer), then adding this line should have no effect. Its "a magic incantation" - you don't know why it helped, or when it will help. It would help to figure out what was wrong in the first place. For example, maybe the view needed to be refreshed, so the "straightforward" answer would have been "Invalidate(); Update();", and this  triggered *what was really needed*.

Answer (score -1):

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem("item1");
item.SubItems.Add("subitem"); //add subitem if applicable
listview1.Items.Add(item);
```

this Result can be sold your problem

Comment: This doesn't really add any value to the discussion imo.