# Trying to display items in a listview

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, listview

I am trying to add results obtained from a search to a listview but when the values are displayed it does not come out as expected. I would like it to have appropriate headings along with the appropriate results listed under the headings, any advice or help would be much appreciated.

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=*****;Initial Catalog=Database name;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    using (SqlDataAdapter sdagetAssetSearch = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From Asset WHERE (AssetName LIKE '%" + txtSimpleSearch.Text + "%') OR (ModelNumber LIKE '%" + txtSimpleSearch.Text + "%')", cn))
    {
        DataTable getAssetSearchDt = new DataTable();
        sdagetAssetSearch.Fill(getAssetSearchDt);

        for (int p = 0; p < getAssetSearchDt.Rows.Count; p++)
        {
            ListViewItem listitem = new ListViewItem(getAssetSearchDt.Rows[p]["AssetName"].ToString());

            lstDisplayAssetSearchDetails.Items.Add(getAssetSearchDt.Rows[p]["AssetName"].ToString());
            lstDisplayAssetSearchDetails.Items.Add(getAssetSearchDt.Rows[p]["Category"].ToString());
            lstDisplayAssetSearchDetails.Items.Add(getAssetSearchDt.Rows[p]["ModelNumber"].ToString());
            lstDisplayAssetSearchDetails.Items.Add(listitem);                        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection as you pass the values in the textboxes directly to the database. Use parameters instead.

Comment: What [View type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.view%28VS.85%29.aspx) is your listbox?

Comment: @laura, have you stepped through the code to make sure that you are in fact returning any records from the sqlDataAdapter..? also I would do a `foreach (DataRow row in getAssetSearchDt.Row)` instead..

Comment: As stuard says, your database code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You could change it to call a stored procedure, or use a parameterized query. See here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: @stuartd how do I find out the view type for my list box? I apologise but this is new for me, Thank you for the advice to prevent the sql injection, I will correct this by passing through a parameters as you said

Comment: @laura in design mode, look at the View property of the listview. - column headers are only displayed in `Details` mode - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146567/winforms-listview-not-showing-items-in-detailsview) for some code to do that

Comment: @methodman it is displaying data(records), it just have a bit of formatting issue, I would like to display under appropriate columns

Comment: @stuartd it is currently largeIcon, when I change it to detail it no longer displays anything in the listview when I preform a search

Comment: @laura see [the question I linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146567/winforms-listview-not-showing-items-in-detailsview) for how to add columns and display items in Details mode

Comment: @ stuartd did it another way as I could not get that way to work, thanks for the help, now passing the values through parameters instead of textboxes

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you have created columns or not. But if you want to display columns in ListView then you have to add Columns like this.

```
lstDisplayAssetSearchDetails.Columns.Add("Assets Name");
lstDisplayAssetSearchDetails.Columns.Add("Category");
lstDisplayAssetSearchDetails.Columns.Add("Model Number");
```

you can  add this code in Form_Load or in Constructor after InitializeComponent method call.

The one more thing is that you need to set is `ViewType`. It should be `DetailView`.

You can set this property at runtime before adding columns or at design time directly from the property window.

```
lstDisplayAssetSearchDetails.View = View.Details;
```

Then now your ListView is ready to populate data into it. But, make sure that every time when you fill the data the previous items should be cleared. in your code you have not cleared the items before filling the `ListView`.

```
lstDisplayAssetSearchDetails.Items.Clear();

for (int p = 0; p < getAssetSearchDt.Rows.Count; p++)
{
    .....
```

This line should be added before starting the loop. So, that will clear the items before populating new.

You can see that we have added 4 columns above. if I want to fill the data into all of the columns for each item. then each item should have added at-least 2 subitems.

```
ListViewItem listitem = new ListViewItem(getAssetSearchDt.Rows[p]["AssetName"].ToString());
listitem.SubItems.Add(getAssetSearchDt.Rows[p]["Category"].ToString());
listitem.SubItems.Add(getAssetSearchDt.Rows[p]["ModelNumber"].ToString());
lstDisplayAssetSearchDetails.Items.Add(listitem);
```

We are not going to add AssetName in Subitem list. because the first column is main `ListItem` and furthers are `SubItems`.

Comment: _the first column is main ListItem and furthers are SubItems_ Also: SubItems[0] __is__ the first column, read it is an alternative way to access it.